# When Doing the Setup of ADFS :-Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: adfs

During the *ADFS configuration wizard* at the time of installation I got this error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular SQL rather than Windows Internal Database (if you are using that). This bug has been reported a few times. Please refer to this similar thread. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72f39daf-7641-42ab-8273-fc73497dc18c/adfs-install-failure-in-azure-vm?forum=Geneva